# And in multiple file conditions does not work on Maven profile

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm using Maven 3.5+ that I've read that Maven 3.2.2+ supports And condition in activation of profiles. So I've added multiple condition in activation tag of a profile as below:

```
 <activation>
     <file>
         <exists>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/index.html</exists>
          <missing>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/app/gen-src/metadata.json</missing>
     </file>
 </activation>
```

And I put it in parent's pom.xml. and the profile should execute when the child project contains index.html but does not have metadata.json.
When I compile the child project that has both index.html and metadata.json, the profile activated and plugins going to execute. but the profile should not active in this situation. I think conditions ORed by maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the v3.5.0 [`ActivationFile` javadoc](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/ActivationFile.html) (couldn't find the source yet) and [`FileProfileActivator` sources](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/profile/activation/FileProfileActivator.java), currently that does not seem to be possible with multiple files, and there's [this issue open](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5909).

The *file-activation-configuration* accepts 2 parameters, one for existing and one for missing file. So both the parameters affect the same configuration, and you can only have one such configuration.

As a result, it will look for either an existing or a missing file, in this order if both values are set, but not for the both of them. Unfortunately I couldn't find a work-around so far...

1) `ActivationFile` javadoc:

> public class **ActivationFile**
>   
>   extends Object
>   
>   implements Serializable, Cloneable, InputLocationTracker
>
> This is the file specification used to activate the profile. The missing value is the location of a file that needs to exist, and if it doesn't, the profile will be activated. On the other hand, exists will test for the existence of the file and if it is there, the profile will be activated.
>   Variable interpolation for these file specifications is limited to ${basedir}, System properties and request properties.

2) `FileProfileActivator` sources (please note that I've omitted some interpolation code for the sake of brevity)

```java
@Override
public boolean isActive(Profile profile, ProfileActivationContext context, ModelProblemCollector problems) {
    Activation activation = profile.getActivation();

    if (activation == null) {
        return false;
    }

    ActivationFile file = activation.getFile();

    if (file == null) {
        return false;
    }

    String path;
    boolean missing;

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(file.getExists())) {
        path = file.getExists();
        missing = false;
    } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(file.getMissing())) {
        path = file.getMissing();
        missing = true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    /* ===> interpolation code omitted for the sake of brevity <=== */

    // replace activation value with interpolated value
    if (missing) {
        file.setMissing(path);
    } else {
        file.setExists(path);
    }

    File f = new File(path);

    if (!f.isAbsolute()) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean fileExists = f.exists();

    return missing ? !fileExists : fileExists;
}
```